# Writing unit testing for my controller in Node.js using Jest

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs

I am currently working on a project and have encountered a challenge in writing a unit test for a specific scenario in my controller code. Below is the relevant code snippet:

```
export const agentCall = async ({ body, user }, res) => {
    try {
        // ... [code omitted for brevity]

        const dummyContact = new ContactModel({
            firstName: variables?.prospectName || '',
            phone_number: parsedPhoneNumber,
            user: user._id,
            variables: Object.entries(variables).map(([key, value]) => ({
                variable: key,
                value
            }))
        })

        await dummyContact.save()

        const call = await createCall({
            agent,
            contact: dummyContact,
            priority: 100
        })

        return res.status(201).json({ status: 'success', call_id: call._id })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error, 'error => ')
        return res.status(500).json({ status: 'error' })
    }
}
```

I have attempted to write a unit test for the success case, but it is giving me a 500 error. Here is the test code I have written:

```
test('should create a call successfully with valid data', async () => {

    const mockAgentModel = {
        findOne: jest
            .fn()
            .mockResolvedValue(
                Promise.resolve({ _id: 'valid_id', agentName: 'test' })
            )
    }
    const mockContactSave = jest.fn()
    const mockCreateCall = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({ _id: 'call_id' })

    jest.spyOn(AgentModel, 'findOne').mockImplementation(() => mockAgentModel)
    jest.spyOn(ContactModel.prototype, 'save').mockImplementation(mockContactSave)
    jest.spyOn(call, 'create').mockImplementation(() => mockCreateCall)

    await agentCall(req, res)

    expect(res.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(201)
    expect(mockContactSave).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Could you review the provided controller code and the corresponding test code? I am particularly interested in understanding why the test is resulting in a 500 error and if there are any improvements or corrections needed in the test implementation.

Comment: _Don't_ unit test controllers. Also you seem to have persistence layer code in your controllers, which is not good architecture (and makes it harder to test the actual business logic). You shouldn't have to mock so many things you don't own (Express request/response, DB models, ...).

Comment: Can you guide me what should I test then?